# Azure Custom Vision model retrain

Tags: azure, prediction, azure-cognitive-services

We use Azure Custom Vision service to detect products on store shelves. This works pretty well, but we can't understand why each subsequent iteration of training makes the forecast worse. Does the service create a model from scratch in each iteration, or does it retrain the same model?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're using the classifier or the object detector, each time you train, you create a new *iteration* with its own updated performance metrics.

That means that each *iteration* in a project is independent, built on different sets of training images.

To maintain high performance don't delete existing images from the previous *iteration* before retraining, because by retraining you're basically creating a new model based on the images you currently have tagged.

It is also stated in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/getting-started-build-a-classifier#manage-training-iterations) for the classifier, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/get-started-build-detector#manage-training-iterations) for the object detector.